# Boost Array data issue

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, c++11

Hey!

I now try to send packet with boost asio, and i store packet data in boost array.
Before i was sending it by dynamic allocated char array.

I declare array by `boost::array<char, 5824>`

And after it I set normally values in my array.

I send it by boost asio (synchronously).
But problem is there when client receive packet, about 1000 first bytes are ok, but other contains random data.

What I doing there wrong ?
I tried different combinations, but result is same.
Thanks!

## edit

I fill up data by memcpy on array pointer obtained by method array.data(); 
For example `memcpy(array.data()+10, &chararray, 15);` 
Data is sended by `boost::asio::write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(array));`

Comment: How are you sending the data?

Comment: Please show us the code you use to fill and send the array. If possible, please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I added example of filling it with data, and send function.

Comment: @Mgetz thank you for help! When i changed it into std::array it started working ;).
But it seems it still have random bytes at all.

Comment: @user3126089 I've made my comment into an answer

Comment: You are only copying 15 bytes to the array, which contains uninitialized `char`s everywhere else. What values are you expecting after 10+15 bytes?

Comment: @juanchopanza I put it as example, i use memcpy to put int's long's etc into array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)? Boost recommends it as a replacement given that it's been added to the standard library. Then you can use the [`fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill) member to initialize it, or use a `{}` initalizer to zero it in place.

```
using socketData = std::array<char, 5824>;
socketData data{}; // uninitialized per standard, the {} zeros

socketData::iterator iter = data.begin();

// write data using iterators
boost::asio::write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(array));
```

Comment: You don't need to fill with zeros. You can say `socketData data{};`. But your code is not doing the same as OP's. They are copying from a different array.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've updated my example for your zeroing recommendation. I'm not seeing their copy but that would be easily achieved using `std::copy` anyway.

Comment: They `memcpy` 15 bytes from one array to another, starting at the 10th position of the destination array. Yes, you can do that with `std::copy` and it would be easier to read :)